# Autocorrelation function in c++ boost

Tags: c++, boost

I have an issue with the possible trend detection in a series of data, represented by a vector which is increasing at every step of the loop. Is it OK to find the autocorrelation of this vector in order to detect the abrupt changes within the data series?

If it is I`m curious to find if anyone has tried to use c++ boost functions only to calculate the autocorrelation in this scenario (possibly boost time series)?

In general the algorithim should be something like

```
for (;;) {
    //calculate the number of interest;
    //push_back this number to a vector
    //autocorrelation of (vector, vector)
    //output the coefficient
}
```

Comment: can you not store the differential, and print the growth each step? You could even show the deviation from the running average. Look at Boost Accumulators to get the running average for free

Comment: this can definitely be a good approach, but changes can also be gradual, so the brute-force difference might not do any good, but i`ll try the Accumulators approach for sure.

Comment: Hmm? I didn't suggest to look at the individual difference. I suggested to look at the running _average_ difference over time

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Indeed the average should be more sensitive than adjacent differences.

Comment: Isn't the autocorrelation a time series instead of a single coefficient? I.e. `AC(dt) = sum(v[t]*v[v+dt])` ?